# Fetch results that do not have specific values

Tags: sql, oracle

Sample data (Oracle DB)

```
HID   Result    ResultDate
6150  Interim    23-03-1990
6150  FINAL      24-03-1990
6150  Interim    25-05-1990
6180  Interim    30-08-2016
6190  Interim    31-08-2016
```

I have been asked to find all the HID's which do not have Final Results.

And the expected output is

```
    HID   Result    ResultDate
    6180  Interim    30-08-2016
    6190  Interim    31-08-2016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option `count` with `case`:

```
select hid
from yourtable
group by hid
having count(case when result = 'FINAL' then 1 end) > 0
```

This returns `6180` and `6190` since they don't have any corresponding rows with `result = 'final'`.

---

Given your edits, here's an option using `not exists`:

```
select * 
from yourtable y
where not exists (
    select 1
    from yourtable y2
    where y.hid = y2.hid and y2.result = 'FINAL'
)
```

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks a lot